# What "promise" does Coop make to Murph?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, interstellar

In the film *Interstellar*, the granddad said that Coop needs to sort it out with Murphy before he goes, and not to make any promises he couldn't keep.

But at the end of the film, while Coop was talking to Murphy, Coop said "how did you know?", to which Murphy replied "because my dad promised me". When in the film did he make this promise?

Answer (score 4):

Cooper promises to Murph that he will return.

Comment: Not trying to be funny about your answer, but he never said 'I Promise', A promise isn't a promise without saying 'I Promise' before or at the end of whatever he was promising???

Comment: @CarlHarrison no, not always. I swear, trust me, believe me, etc.